# I can't install or remove mariadb

Tags: software-installation, uninstall, mariadb

Recently I've installed Ubuntu 17.04. I was trying to install `mariadb`, so I installed all the packages. I don't know what happened, but whenever I install anything, try to connect to the Internet with Wi-fi, uninstall packages, I always get this error:

```
Failed to start MariaDB-server-10.0
```

So I decided to uninstall it and reinstall it by these commands

```
apt-get remove --purge mariadb-server mariadb-client
apt-get autoremove --purge
rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/
rm -rf /etc/mysql/
sudo apt-get install maria-db-server
```

I get this error now

```
Failed to start MariaDB database server.
```

Does anyone have any idea ?

Comment: I have no idea; but I'm guessing that apt-get/wifi uses mariaDB to store its package, wifi-network databases, which is now not available.  you may now need to install it manually (using `dpkg`).  `dpkg-reconfigure` may have been an easier way to reset mariadb, and viewing your command `history` can be useful to see what causes a mistake,

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure it and from the commands seems you didn't.

After installing it you need to : `mysql_secure_installation` and configure it.